# IBM Worklight - Is it possible to call Stored Procedures with the Out parameter?

Tags: stored-procedures, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Is it possible to call a Stored Procedure in Worklight through the `WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure` API method that requires an *Out* parameter?

Comment: consider showing what you have tried or researched

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBM Worklight - How to get OUT parameter when invoking a stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248450/ibm-worklight-how-to-get-out-parameter-when-invoking-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, WL SQL adapter does not support out parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to override Worklight and call stored procedures via Java to get OUT params. See answer here [IBM Worklight - How to get OUT parameter when invoking a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248450/ibm-worklight-how-to-get-out-parameter-when-invoking-a-stored-procedure)

This approach can be used to get OUT parameters as well as Ref Cursors (SYS_REFCURSOR) which also are not supported.