# IBM Worklight - How to call a Stored Procedure with the "OUT" parameter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We using a SQL adapter and I'm getting the below error while invoking the Stored Procedure. we Our database is Oracle 11g. Below is our adapter and procedures.

```
function deals(param) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : "deals_proc",
        parameters : []
    });
}
```

and the procedure is

```
create or replace procedure deals_proc(c1 out sys_refcursor ) AS 
begin 
open c1 for 
select CATEGORYNAME from DEALS;
end deals_proc;
```

and the error 'm getting is

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: Failed to retrieve data with procedure : deals_proc"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

in console error message is

```
Failed to retrieve data with procedure : deals_proc
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project Test]java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DEALS_PROC'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to retrieve data with procedure : deals_proc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight does not support the `out` parameter in SQL adapters. See this question: [IBM Worklight - How to get OUT parameter when invoking a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248450/ibm-worklight-how-to-get-out-parameter-when-invoking-a-stored-procedure)

The question I linked you to also contains an answer providing an elaborate workaround if you wish the try it (basically, override Worklight and implement it in Java code).