# getting error for Accessing stored proc in ibm mobilefirst

Tags: oracle, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

i am trying to work with stored procedure written inside a package but i am not able to access:

> Runtime: Failed to retrieve data with procedure :
>   XXMOB_LOGIN_AN.login_prc

In the adapter JS:

```
function procedure2(p_usrname,p_password) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : "XXMOB_LOGIN_AN.login_prc",
        parameters : []
    });
}
```

The procedure:

```
create or replace PACKAGE XXMOB_LOGIN_AN AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
 Procedure login_prc (
      p_usrname        IN       VARCHAR2,
      p_password       IN       VARCHAR2,
      p_person_id      OUT      VARCHAR2,
      p_groups_id      OUT      VARCHAR2,
      p_person_login   OUT      VARCHAR2,
      p_person_role    OUT      VARCHAR2,
      p_user_id        OUT      VARCHAR2,
      p_welcome        OUT      VARCHAR2,
      p_return         OUT      VARCHAR2,
      P_return_message out      varchar2

   );
END XXMOB_LOGIN_AN;
```

In the adapter XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wl:adapter name="strprc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
    xmlns:sql="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/sql">

    <displayName>strprc</displayName>
    <description>strprc</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
            <!-- Example for using a JNDI data source, replace with actual data source name -->
            <!-- <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName> -->

            <!-- Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder -->
            <dataSourceDefinition>
                <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@</url>
                <user>***</user>
                <password>***</password> 
            </dataSourceDefinition>
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <!-- Replace this with appropriate procedures -->
    <procedure name="procedure2"/>
</wl:adapter>
```

Comment: Run your app in the preview from the browser, with the chrome devtools console open - what error do you see there when the procedure invocation fails? (you may need to refresh the screen)

Comment: i m testing for adapter to backend initially so i didmt write any client side code

Comment: So it is likely the address of the backend you are attempting to connect to.

Comment: yes backend database i m trying and  also there is no issues in connection because earlier i have worked for normal sql queries . it worked well.i am trying to connect to database from adapter here using stored sql procedures

Comment: Maybe this is related? "OUT" is not supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798817/ibm-worklight-how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-the-out-parameter

Comment: ya i checked on that any other way is it possible ????because i feel comfortable with js and can u pls check my **function procedure2** on top whether i have written in a right way ??.my task is to pass username and pwd and get responses

Comment: I don't have working knowledge with Oracle.

Comment: You did not provide your procedure2.

Comment: sry its with xml updated nw @IdanAdar

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, Worklight does not support the `out` parameter in SQL adapters. See this question: [IBM Worklight - How to get OUT parameter when invoking a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248450/ibm-worklight-how-to-get-out-parameter-when-invoking-a-stored-procedure)

The question I linked you to also contains an answer providing an elaborate workaround if you wish the try it (basically, override Worklight and implement it in Java code).