# Stored procedure in mysql calling from wl sql adapter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

this is my stored procedure:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE get_idS(OUT a INT,OUT b INT,OUT c INT,OUT d int)
       begin
         select * into a from t1;
         select * into b from t2;
          select * into c from t3;
          select * into d from t4;

   end
```

each table contains one col id and one row,

calling function

```
function callStored5() {

    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : "GET_IDS",
        parameters : ["@A","@B","@C","@D"]
    });
}
```

after calling this from sqladapter below invocationresult is obtained

```
  {
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "updateStatementResult": {
      "updateCount": 0
   }
  }
```

is this invocationresult  correct???

Comment: But what is your invocation function?

Comment: Please provide more complete code samples - a lot more. Also please clarify what your question really is.

Comment: `select *  a from t1;` doesn't look like a valid SQL syntax to me... It should either be * or a, not both?

Comment: @IdanAdar, above mentioned is my invocation function

Comment: @user3510619, please reply to Nathan's questions.

Comment: @NathanH actualy the qyery is select * into a from t1; a is output parameter in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you are trying to return OUT Params from the proc which are not supported in the SQL adapters, only what is returned with key word return. This has been asked before. This can be accomplished by calling Java code from the adapter. See answers here:

[IBM Worklight - How to get OUT parameter when invoking a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248450/ibm-worklight-how-to-get-out-parameter-when-invoking-a-stored-procedure)