# How to resolve output parameter issue in sql adapter of worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

[IBM Worklight - Is it possible to call Stored Procedures with the Out parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024072/ibm-worklight-is-it-possible-to-call-stored-procedures-with-the-out-parameter)

In this link i found we can't call stored procedures with output parameter. But usually stored procedures are with input and output parameters. In this case how can i resolve the issue.

Please help me...

Comment: In the same question you linked to, there is an answer to a workaround. That, or you can use Java adapters (available starting MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 and above).

Comment: I am using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 only. Tell me how to work with Java adapters...

Comment: You can read more about Java adapters here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/java-adapter/